# Find serial ports on unix systems

Tags: linux, macos, unix, serialization, arduino

I need to develop a service that will actively find new serial devices connected and spin a new thread for that serial device

The main reason is that we have a unix machine (some places a mac, others a linux and some even a raspberryPi). This machine will have many devices connected (external HDDs, Arduino(s) and phones, etc).

The software will look for all serial ports and find the arduinos connected, then it will spin a thread to handle that arduino.

Our problems are:

1. List only serial devices in any platform

   - On mac is /dev/tty.(any name here)
   - On linux is /dev/ttyUSB(#)
2. Detect only the arduinos

   - Some devices are listed as ttyUSB and others as ttyModem or even ttyACM
   - In linux i could create a udev rule, but on mac i didn't find a way

Answer (score 1):

The sigrok project has a subproject called libserialport for finding devices on serial ports on the different operating systems. 
http://sigrok.org/wiki/Libserialport